# How to redirect django to Google directly with Allauth

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, django-allauth

I don't have a code problem but a little aesthetic, I'm trying to make a simple login to an app with Django and be able to enter with Google and when I put the label to enter I would like it to direct the user directly to Google as it usually is, but the label sends them to an intermediate Allaut interface and then press another button and go, I would like to skip that interface but I've tried and it always directs me there

Urls of proyect:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include("allauth.urls")),
    path('', include("pagina.urls"))
]
```

Urls of app:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home),
    path("logout", views.logout_view)
]
```

And the button's code:

```
{% load socialaccount %}
 <h1>Google Login</h1>
 <a href="{% provider_login_url 'google' %}?next=/">Login with Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The page that you call "intermediate allauth interface" and which you call with a GET request, just provides a button that continous the login with a POST request.

You can either

1. change the button on your initial page to initiate directly a POST request instead of GET to login url or
2. set
   SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET=True (but not recommended)

see below from https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html:

SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET (=False)
Controls whether or not the endpoints for initiating a social login (for example, “/accounts/google/login/”) require a POST request to initiate the handshake. For security considerations, it is strongly recommended to require POST requests.

There is two other settings with similar background:
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET